# Quiver plot: ugly arrow heads

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot a vector field. However, the arrowheads in the plot are not scaled properly.  I have tried the tweaks mentioned in this site but I am not able to achieve the desired output.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\def\axisdefaultwidth{12cm}
\def\axisdefaultheight{8cm}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style={scale only axis}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick pos=left,
ytick pos=left,
  xlabel= $z$,
  ylabel= $r$,
  xmin=0, xmax=3,
  ymin=0, ymax=1
         ]
\addplot[blue,quiver={u=\thisrowno{2},v=\thisrowno{3},
scale arrows=100,
every arrow/.append style={%
                    line width=.01+\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/10000,
                    -{Latex[scale length={max(0.01,\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/10000)}]}}
                },-stealth]table [x index=0, y index=1] {IC_act_mode1.dat}; 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is my output:
[image]

Look: the arrowheads are disproportional.

Whereas I want an output like this(generated via matlab)
[image]

Here is the [link to the data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yiq4w0earg0ukfv/IC_act_mode1.dat?dl=0) in my dropbox

How do I get a plot that is similar to the one produced by matlab?

Edit : Here is a smaller sample of the dataset:

```
1e-20   1e-20   8.4374e-07  0
0.15789 1e-20   2.9585e-05  0
0.31579 1e-20   2.2345e-05  0
0.47368 1e-20   1.7572e-05  0
0.63158 1e-20   1.4528e-05  0
0.78947 1e-20   1.3515e-05  0
0.94737 1e-20   1.4516e-05  0
1.1053  1e-20   1.7389e-05  0
1.2632  1e-20   2.1898e-05  0
1.4211  1e-20   2.7675e-05  0
1.5789  1e-20   3.38e-05    0
1.7368  1e-20   3.9467e-05  0
1.8947  1e-20   3.8977e-05  0
2.0526  1e-20   4.2457e-05  0
2.2105  1e-20   0.00020037  0
2.3684  1e-20   0.00065628  0
2.5263  1e-20   -0.00025975 0
2.6842  1e-20   -0.00033465 0
2.8421  1e-20   -7.7805e-05 0
3   1e-20   -7.1355e-07 0
1e-20   0.052632    1.7999e-13  1.2513e-06
0.15789 0.052632    2.96e-05    1.1807e-06
0.31579 0.052632    2.2346e-05  1.1457e-06
0.47368 0.052632    1.7581e-05  1.0041e-06
0.63158 0.052632    1.4536e-05  8.1481e-07
0.78947 0.052632    1.3524e-05  6.1724e-07
0.94737 0.052632    1.4527e-05  4.2964e-07
1.1053  0.052632    1.7401e-05  2.6381e-07
1.2632  0.052632    2.1911e-05  1.2851e-07
1.4211  0.052632    2.7688e-05  3.1813e-08
1.5789  0.052632    3.3814e-05  -1.7567e-08
1.7368  0.052632    3.9482e-05  -9.8503e-09
1.8947  0.052632    3.8995e-05  6.7303e-08
2.0526  0.052632    4.249e-05   2.4326e-07
2.2105  0.052632    0.00020043  6.1149e-07
2.3684  0.052632    0.00065625  1.1287e-06
2.5263  0.052632    -0.00025933 1.0634e-06
2.6842  0.052632    -0.00033483 1.6225e-06
2.8421  0.052632    -7.7845e-05 1.3419e-06
3   0.052632    -2.775e-13  1.5552e-06
1e-20   0.10526 5.4022e-12  3.9747e-06
0.15789 0.10526 2.956e-05   4.391e-06
0.31579 0.10526 2.2295e-05  3.7678e-06
0.47368 0.10526 1.7542e-05  2.9333e-06
0.63158 0.10526 1.4513e-05  2.1042e-06
0.78947 0.10526 1.3516e-05  1.3889e-06
0.94737 0.10526 1.4528e-05  8.2426e-07
1.1053  0.10526 1.7408e-05  4.1246e-07
1.2632  0.10526 2.192e-05   1.4635e-07
1.4211  0.10526 2.7697e-05  1.6785e-08
1.5789  0.10526 3.3824e-05  1.8305e-08
1.7368  0.10526 3.9493e-05  1.5961e-07
1.8947  0.10526 3.9011e-05  4.6644e-07
2.0526  0.10526 4.2503e-05  8.8809e-07
2.2105  0.10526 0.00020045  1.1471e-06
2.3684  0.10526 0.00065635  1.6506e-06
2.5263  0.10526 -0.00025942 1.237e-06
2.6842  0.10526 -0.00033467 2.3078e-07
2.8421  0.10526 -7.7677e-05 2.6587e-06
3   0.10526 -3.1943e-13 3.4593e-06
1e-20   0.15789 8.7685e-12  4.265e-06
0.15789 0.15789 2.9496e-05  4.5454e-06
0.31579 0.15789 2.2221e-05  4.1445e-06
0.47368 0.15789 1.7485e-05  3.4443e-06
0.63158 0.15789 1.4486e-05  2.6596e-06
0.78947 0.15789 1.3515e-05  1.9155e-06
0.94737 0.15789 1.4544e-05  1.2648e-06
1.1053  0.15789 1.7433e-05  7.3172e-07
1.2632  0.15789 2.1949e-05  3.3043e-07
1.4211  0.15789 2.7727e-05  7.2666e-08
1.5789  0.15789 3.3854e-05  -2.7276e-08
1.7368  0.15789 3.9528e-05  5.3773e-08
1.8947  0.15789 3.9059e-05  3.5666e-07
2.0526  0.15789 4.2565e-05  9.265e-07
2.2105  0.15789 0.00020053  1.7786e-06
2.3684  0.15789 0.00065659  3.0347e-06
2.5263  0.15789 -0.00025964 3.0478e-06
2.6842  0.15789 -0.00033437 3.183e-06
2.8421  0.15789 -7.7488e-05 4.1059e-06
3   0.15789 -2.6925e-13 4.6889e-06
1e-20   0.21053 1.1944e-11  4.3044e-06
0.15789 0.21053 2.9428e-05  4.3849e-06
0.31579 0.21053 2.2144e-05  4.2897e-06
0.47368 0.21053 1.7427e-05  3.8091e-06
0.63158 0.21053 1.4459e-05  3.1393e-06
0.78947 0.21053 1.3514e-05  2.4167e-06
0.94737 0.21053 1.4562e-05  1.7102e-06
1.1053  0.21053 1.7461e-05  1.0686e-06
1.2632  0.21053 2.198e-05   5.3164e-07
1.4211  0.21053 2.7759e-05  1.3585e-07
1.5789  0.21053 3.3886e-05  -8.1255e-08
1.7368  0.21053 3.9565e-05  -8.0444e-08
1.8947  0.21053 3.9111e-05  1.9444e-07
2.0526  0.21053 4.2633e-05  9.0241e-07
2.2105  0.21053 0.00020062  2.42e-06
2.3684  0.21053 0.00065684  4.5077e-06
2.5263  0.21053 -0.00025987 5.0272e-06
2.6842  0.21053 -0.00033405 6.583e-06
2.8421  0.21053 -7.7297e-05 5.5665e-06
3   0.21053 -2.096e-13  5.8489e-06
1e-20   0.26316 6.5923e-12  6.4593e-06
0.15789 0.26316 2.9403e-05  6.8318e-06
0.31579 0.26316 2.2095e-05  6.3322e-06
0.47368 0.26316 1.7398e-05  5.354e-06
0.63158 0.26316 1.4466e-05  4.2177e-06
0.78947 0.26316 1.3552e-05  3.1078e-06
0.94737 0.26316 1.462e-05   2.1052e-06
1.1053  0.26316 1.7528e-05  1.2554e-06
1.2632  0.26316 2.2051e-05  5.9073e-07
1.4211  0.26316 2.783e-05   1.3944e-07
1.5789  0.26316 3.3958e-05  -6.7783e-08
1.7368  0.26316 3.9643e-05  9.0248e-09
1.8947  0.26316 3.9213e-05  4.3744e-07
2.0526  0.26316 4.2808e-05  1.3465e-06
2.2105  0.26316 0.00020092  2.9442e-06
2.3684  0.26316 0.00065714  5.2573e-06
2.5263  0.26316 -0.00025919 5.5989e-06
2.6842  0.26316 -0.00033414 6.3973e-06
2.8421  0.26316 -7.7358e-05 6.9595e-06
3   0.26316 2.1642e-13  7.6471e-06
1e-20   0.31579 -3.5583e-13 9.0103e-06
0.15789 0.31579 2.9385e-05  9.7668e-06
0.31579 0.31579 2.2051e-05  8.7299e-06
0.47368 0.31579 1.7375e-05  7.1197e-06
0.63158 0.31579 1.4481e-05  5.4082e-06
0.78947 0.31579 1.3598e-05  3.8344e-06
0.94737 0.31579 1.4685e-05  2.4909e-06
1.1053  0.31579 1.7603e-05  1.4141e-06
1.2632  0.31579 2.2129e-05  6.2321e-07
1.4211  0.31579 2.7908e-05  1.3188e-07
1.5789  0.31579 3.4036e-05  -4.168e-08
1.7368  0.31579 3.9728e-05  1.4036e-07
1.8947  0.31579 3.9324e-05  7.5628e-07
2.0526  0.31579 4.3003e-05  1.8781e-06
2.2105  0.31579 0.00020127  3.4464e-06
2.3684  0.31579 0.00065744  5.8715e-06
2.5263  0.31579 -0.00025833 5.9074e-06
2.6842  0.31579 -0.0003343  5.5404e-06
2.8421  0.31579 -7.7465e-05 8.3398e-06
3   0.31579 7.1109e-13  9.5648e-06
1e-20   0.36842 -7.7856e-13 1.0093e-05
0.15789 0.36842 2.9234e-05  1.0734e-05
0.31579 0.36842 2.1874e-05  9.6609e-06
0.47368 0.36842 1.7253e-05  7.9444e-06
0.63158 0.36842 1.4432e-05  6.1038e-06
0.78947 0.36842 1.3607e-05  4.3905e-06
0.94737 0.36842 1.4731e-05  2.902e-06
1.1053  0.36842 1.767e-05   1.6839e-06
1.2632  0.36842 2.2204e-05  7.66e-07
1.4211  0.36842 2.7985e-05  1.7187e-07
1.5789  0.36842 3.4113e-05  -7.0507e-08
1.7368  0.36842 3.9814e-05  8.4265e-08
1.8947  0.36842 3.944e-05   7.2521e-07
2.0526  0.36842 4.3179e-05  1.9832e-06
2.2105  0.36842 0.00020155  3.9843e-06
2.3684  0.36842 0.000658    7.0747e-06
2.5263  0.36842 -0.00025845 7.261e-06
2.6842  0.36842 -0.0003338  7.5589e-06
2.8421  0.36842 -7.7138e-05 9.8347e-06
3   0.36842 6.4554e-13  1.1206e-05
1e-20   0.42105 2.2928e-12  1.0391e-05
0.15789 0.42105 2.9011e-05  1.0648e-05
0.31579 0.42105 2.1627e-05  9.8069e-06
0.47368 0.42105 1.7078e-05  8.2653e-06
0.63158 0.42105 1.435e-05   6.5344e-06
0.78947 0.42105 1.3598e-05  4.8552e-06
0.94737 0.42105 1.4769e-05  3.3266e-06
1.1053  0.42105 1.7732e-05  2.0133e-06
1.2632  0.42105 2.2277e-05  9.6783e-07
1.4211  0.42105 2.806e-05   2.373e-07
1.5789  0.42105 3.4189e-05  -1.2874e-07
1.7368  0.42105 3.99e-05    -7.2172e-08
1.8947  0.42105 3.9559e-05  5.0685e-07
2.0526  0.42105 4.3344e-05  1.8601e-06
2.2105  0.42105 0.0002018   4.5413e-06
2.3684  0.42105 0.00065868  8.5931e-06
2.5263  0.42105 -0.00025907 9.1736e-06
2.6842  0.42105 -0.00033296 1.1117e-05
2.8421  0.42105 -7.6579e-05 1.1391e-05
3   0.42105 2.8001e-13  1.2698e-05
1e-20   0.47368 -5.1331e-12 1.2141e-05
0.15789 0.47368 2.8854e-05  1.2638e-05
0.31579 0.47368 2.144e-05   1.1422e-05
0.47368 0.47368 1.6974e-05  9.4866e-06
0.63158 0.47368 1.434e-05   7.4222e-06
0.78947 0.47368 1.3653e-05  5.4687e-06
0.94737 0.47368 1.4862e-05  3.7187e-06
1.1053  0.47368 1.7845e-05  2.2334e-06
1.2632  0.47368 2.2398e-05  1.0644e-06
1.4211  0.47368 2.8182e-05  2.582e-07
1.5789  0.47368 3.4311e-05  -1.3601e-07
1.7368  0.47368 4.0032e-05  -5.8545e-08
1.8947  0.47368 3.9732e-05  5.9918e-07
2.0526  0.47368 4.3646e-05  2.0988e-06
2.2105  0.47368 0.00020236  4.9815e-06
2.3684  0.47368 0.00065936  9.5184e-06
2.5263  0.47368 -0.00025822 1.0277e-05
2.6842  0.47368 -0.00033289 1.1688e-05
2.8421  0.47368 -7.6485e-05 1.2963e-05
3   0.47368 3.3082e-14  1.4463e-05
1e-20   0.52632 -1.9461e-11 1.4846e-05
0.15789 0.52632 2.8741e-05  1.5993e-05
0.31579 0.52632 2.1293e-05  1.4003e-05
0.47368 0.52632 1.6918e-05  1.13e-05
0.63158 0.52632 1.4376e-05  8.6106e-06
0.78947 0.52632 1.375e-05   6.18e-06
0.94737 0.52632 1.4993e-05  4.0894e-06
1.1053  0.52632 1.7993e-05  2.3817e-06
1.2632  0.52632 2.255e-05   1.0918e-06
1.4211  0.52632 2.8335e-05  2.4985e-07
1.5789  0.52632 3.4465e-05  -1.0977e-07
1.7368  0.52632 4.0195e-05  6.6866e-08
1.8947  0.52632 3.994e-05   8.9572e-07
2.0526  0.52632 4.4038e-05  2.5755e-06
2.2105  0.52632 0.00020313  5.3447e-06
2.3684  0.52632 0.00066003  1.0054e-05
2.5263  0.52632 -0.00025639 1.0849e-05
2.6842  0.52632 -0.00033333 1.0296e-05
2.8421  0.52632 -7.6696e-05 1.4547e-05
3   0.52632 -1.3581e-13 1.6405e-05
1e-20   0.57895 1.9459e-12  1.5868e-05
0.15789 0.57895 2.8259e-05  1.6179e-05
0.31579 0.57895 2.084e-05   1.4205e-05
0.47368 0.57895 1.6656e-05  1.1611e-05
0.63158 0.57895 1.4283e-05  9.0415e-06
0.78947 0.57895 1.3766e-05  6.6608e-06
0.94737 0.57895 1.5072e-05  4.5349e-06
1.1053  0.57895 1.8103e-05  2.7277e-06
1.2632  0.57895 2.2675e-05  1.3028e-06
1.4211  0.57895 2.8463e-05  3.1785e-07
1.5789  0.57895 3.4593e-05  -1.7029e-07
1.7368  0.57895 4.0335e-05  -9.8335e-08
1.8947  0.57895 4.0123e-05  6.4641e-07
2.0526  0.57895 4.4318e-05  2.3512e-06
2.2105  0.57895 0.00020366  5.7269e-06
2.3684  0.57895 0.00066134  1.1589e-05
2.5263  0.57895 -0.00025728 1.2764e-05
2.6842  0.57895 -0.0003322  1.3937e-05
2.8421  0.57895 -7.5848e-05 1.6199e-05
3   0.57895 7.2023e-14  1.8663e-05
1e-20   0.63158 1.2082e-11  1.7249e-05
0.15789 0.63158 2.7747e-05  1.7216e-05
0.31579 0.63158 2.0393e-05  1.4974e-05
0.47368 0.63158 1.6438e-05  1.228e-05
0.63158 0.63158 1.4237e-05  9.6667e-06
0.78947 0.63158 1.3823e-05  7.2119e-06
0.94737 0.63158 1.5185e-05  4.9714e-06
1.1053  0.63158 1.8245e-05  3.0279e-06
1.2632  0.63158 2.2828e-05  1.4672e-06
1.4211  0.63158 2.8618e-05  3.6548e-07
1.5789  0.63158 3.475e-05   -2.0782e-07
1.7368  0.63158 4.0502e-05  -1.8601e-07
1.8947  0.63158 4.0334e-05  5.3641e-07
2.0526  0.63158 4.4666e-05  2.2792e-06
2.2105  0.63158 0.00020437  6.0081e-06
2.3684  0.63158 0.00066272  1.2755e-05
2.5263  0.63158 -0.00025716 1.4593e-05
2.6842  0.63158 -0.00033162 1.6328e-05
2.8421  0.63158 -7.5179e-05 1.7887e-05
3   0.63158 1.8444e-13  2.0724e-05
1e-20   0.68421 -1.039e-11  2.0053e-05
0.15789 0.68421 2.7269e-05  2.0953e-05
0.31579 0.68421 2.0051e-05  1.7624e-05
0.47368 0.68421 1.6371e-05  1.4139e-05
0.63158 0.68421 1.4325e-05  1.0917e-05
0.78947 0.68421 1.3985e-05  7.9694e-06
0.94737 0.68421 1.5381e-05  5.3579e-06
1.1053  0.68421 1.8456e-05  3.1663e-06
1.2632  0.68421 2.3044e-05  1.4751e-06
1.4211  0.68421 2.8835e-05  3.4639e-07
1.5789  0.68421 3.4968e-05  -1.7032e-07
1.7368  0.68421 4.0727e-05  -2.2025e-08
1.8947  0.68421 4.0604e-05  8.8452e-07
2.0526  0.68421 4.5174e-05  2.7373e-06
2.2105  0.68421 0.00020552  6.0696e-06
2.3684  0.68421 0.00066405  1.284e-05
2.5263  0.68421 -0.00025425 1.5736e-05
2.6842  0.68421 -0.0003326  1.4671e-05
2.8421  0.68421 -7.5175e-05 1.9619e-05
3   0.68421 -3.0549e-14 2.2539e-05
1e-20   0.73684 2.7414e-11  2.1994e-05
0.15789 0.73684 2.6104e-05  2.0251e-05
0.31579 0.73684 1.929e-05   1.6956e-05
0.47368 0.73684 1.6017e-05  1.3929e-05
0.63158 0.73684 1.4207e-05  1.1079e-05
0.78947 0.73684 1.3999e-05  8.3238e-06
0.94737 0.73684 1.5468e-05  5.7476e-06
1.1053  0.73684 1.8582e-05  3.4902e-06
1.2632  0.73684 2.3189e-05  1.679e-06
1.4211  0.73684 2.8985e-05  4.1251e-07
1.5789  0.73684 3.5118e-05  -2.356e-07
1.7368  0.73684 4.0887e-05  -2.0945e-07
1.8947  0.73684 4.0795e-05  5.5567e-07
2.0526  0.73684 4.5407e-05  2.2886e-06
2.2105  0.73684 0.00020609  6.0885e-06
2.3684  0.73684 0.00066643  1.4074e-05
2.5263  0.73684 -0.0002561  1.7754e-05
2.6842  0.73684 -0.000331   2.0263e-05
2.8421  0.73684 -7.3456e-05 2.1379e-05
3   0.73684 1.5476e-13  2.686e-05
1e-20   0.78947 -1.1394e-11 2.5445e-05
0.15789 0.78947 2.4852e-05  2.3612e-05
0.31579 0.78947 1.8742e-05  1.9032e-05
0.47368 0.78947 1.5917e-05  1.5339e-05
0.63158 0.78947 1.4277e-05  1.1937e-05
0.78947 0.78947 1.4141e-05  8.7306e-06
0.94737 0.78947 1.5646e-05  5.8408e-06
1.1053  0.78947 1.878e-05   3.4122e-06
1.2632  0.78947 2.3396e-05  1.558e-06
1.4211  0.78947 2.9196e-05  3.509e-07
1.5789  0.78947 3.533e-05   -1.6582e-07
1.7368  0.78947 4.1104e-05  4.0978e-08
1.8947  0.78947 4.1037e-05  1.011e-06
2.0526  0.78947 4.5797e-05  2.7628e-06
2.2105  0.78947 0.00020712  5.7295e-06
2.3684  0.78947 0.00066853  1.3006e-05
2.5263  0.78947 -0.00025282 1.8293e-05
2.6842  0.78947 -0.00033205 1.8884e-05
2.8421  0.78947 -7.2621e-05 2.3086e-05
3   0.78947 2.1021e-13  2.9756e-05
1e-20   0.84211 2.6181e-11  2.9402e-05
0.15789 0.84211 2.2903e-05  2.6023e-05
0.31579 0.84211 1.8052e-05  2.0116e-05
0.47368 0.84211 1.5746e-05  1.591e-05
0.63158 0.84211 1.428e-05   1.2112e-05
0.78947 0.84211 1.4224e-05  8.6188e-06
0.94737 0.84211 1.5771e-05  5.5748e-06
1.1053  0.84211 1.893e-05   3.1143e-06
1.2632  0.84211 2.3558e-05  1.3275e-06
1.4211  0.84211 2.9365e-05  2.5934e-07
1.5789  0.84211 3.5502e-05  -7.6742e-08
1.7368  0.84211 4.1278e-05  3.3018e-07
1.8947  0.84211 4.1226e-05  1.5025e-06
2.0526  0.84211 4.6036e-05  3.2378e-06
2.2105  0.84211 0.0002078   5.134e-06
2.3684  0.84211 0.00067097  1.1052e-05
2.5263  0.84211 -0.00025005 1.7649e-05
2.6842  0.84211 -0.00033258 1.6992e-05
2.8421  0.84211 -7.0897e-05 2.4203e-05
3   0.84211 3.9845e-13  3.302e-05
1e-20   0.89474 6.7778e-12  3.8567e-05
0.15789 0.89474 1.971e-05   2.3981e-05
0.31579 0.89474 1.7071e-05  1.7766e-05
0.47368 0.89474 1.5302e-05  1.4034e-05
0.63158 0.89474 1.4063e-05  1.0648e-05
0.78947 0.89474 1.4137e-05  7.529e-06
0.94737 0.89474 1.5761e-05  4.8099e-06
1.1053  0.89474 1.8965e-05  2.6241e-06
1.2632  0.89474 2.3617e-05  1.0632e-06
1.4211  0.89474 2.9431e-05  1.7757e-07
1.5789  0.89474 3.5564e-05  -1.724e-08
1.7368  0.89474 4.1352e-05  4.7865e-07
1.8947  0.89474 4.1299e-05  1.7e-06
2.0526  0.89474 4.5914e-05  3.3384e-06
2.2105  0.89474 0.0002076   4.3167e-06
2.3684  0.89474 0.00067434  8.3134e-06
2.5263  0.89474 -0.00025178 1.5547e-05
2.6842  0.89474 -0.00033081 1.5755e-05
2.8421  0.89474 -6.7122e-05 2.2837e-05
3   0.89474 -9.28e-14   4.78e-05
1e-20   0.94737 3.2187e-13  6.0353e-05
0.15789 0.94737 1.607e-05   1.9016e-05
0.31579 0.94737 1.6244e-05  1.416e-05
0.47368 0.94737 1.4867e-05  1.1267e-05
0.63158 0.94737 1.383e-05   8.5221e-06
0.78947 0.94737 1.4021e-05  5.943e-06
0.94737 0.94737 1.5711e-05  3.6861e-06
1.1053  0.94737 1.8955e-05  1.8932e-06
1.2632  0.94737 2.3626e-05  6.6272e-07
1.4211  0.94737 2.9442e-05  5.414e-08
1.5789  0.94737 3.5565e-05  8.5454e-08
1.7368  0.94737 4.1378e-05  7.363e-07
1.8947  0.94737 4.1321e-05  2.1158e-06
2.0526  0.94737 4.5637e-05  3.8185e-06
2.2105  0.94737 0.00020675  3.2192e-06
2.3684  0.94737 0.00067775  1.9969e-06
2.5263  0.94737 -0.00025709 1.4034e-05
2.6842  0.94737 -0.00032878 8.2198e-06
2.8421  0.94737 -6.2825e-05 1.6168e-05
3   0.94737 -4.5703e-13 7.8776e-05
1e-20   1   0   0
0.15789 1   0   0
0.31579 1   0   0
0.47368 1   0   0
0.63158 1   0   0
0.78947 1   0   0
0.94737 1   0   0
1.1053  1   0   0
1.2632  1   0   0
1.4211  1   0   0
1.5789  1   0   0
1.7368  1   0   0
1.8947  1   0   0
2.0526  1   0   0
2.2105  1   0   0
2.3684  1   0   0
2.5263  1   0   0
2.6842  1   0   0
2.8421  1   0   0
3   1   0   0
```

Comment: For others to test you should probably also make available the data file.

Comment: @daleif: Is the dropbox link I provided not working?

Comment: It is probably better to make a smaller sample and post it directly to the question. There are many here who will not click on external links, plus your question might unusable for others over time because the DB link might disappear